# How can I access JMeter variables inside a custom java sampler?

Tags: jmeter

I have a java sampler that extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient. I would like to access the thread group loop counter value `{__counter}` from inside the java sampler. How can I achieve this?

`ctx.getParameter("{__counter}");` doesn't seem to work where ctx is `JavaSamplerContext`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you find out how to access the loop count parameter defined for a thread group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[__counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) is a buildin function and not a parameter.

I would suggest to use it in one of the Pre-Processors such as User Parameters and store the returned value to parameter `counterValue`. 
Then you can get the value in your java sampler with 
`ctx.getParameter("counterValue");`

Answer (score -2):

I believe that `ctx.getVariables().get("{__counter}");` is what you're looking for.

See JavaDoc on [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) (`ctx` is a shorthand for JMeterContext).

There is also some useful information on using JMeter API for different purposes in [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide.